# The LINQ expression could not be translated - EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, blazor

**In summary, I'm guessing I can't add any more complex calculations to the `LINQ` expression. Any tips are greatly appreciated!**

This blazor project is using a messy employee table which contains two types of employees, both on the same table

- Domestic employees, uses NRG number to identify them, but their NRG numbers are stored as `string` at `NRG` column, like "`0356`".
- Foreign employees, also uses NRG to identify them, but their `NRG` column contains all `NULL`, their NRG numbers are inside their emails at `AzureEmail` column, like "`johndoe.0356@aaa-bbb.com`"

When domestic employee or foreign employee enter their sales records, they are the "Closer", it is required to enter the "Setter" NRG.

By using the "Setter" NRG number "closer" entered, I want to locate the "Setter" info from the same employee table:

```cs
public async Task Save_to_SalesForm()
{
    await using var context3 = await DBContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    {
            if (salesForm.SetterNrg != null && salesForm.CsTransferCategory == "Local Team")
            {
                setterEmployee = context3.Employees.Where(
                    e => e.AzureAccountEnabled == 1
                    &&
                    (int?)(object?)e.Nrg == salesForm.SetterNrg
                ).OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
                salesForm.SetterAgentFullName = setterEmployee.AzureFullName;
                salesForm.SetterJobTitle = setterEmployee.AzureRole;
                salesForm.SetterEmail = setterEmployee.AzureEmail;
                salesForm.SetterTeam = setterEmployee.AzureTeam;
            }
            if (salesForm.SetterNrg != null && salesForm.CsTransferCategory == "CSR Team (Philippines)")
            {
                setterEmployee = context3.Employees.Where(
                    e => e.Nrg == null
                    &&
                    e.AzureAccountEnabled == 1
                    &&
                    e.AzureEmail.Contains("@aaa-bbb.com")
                    &&
                    (int?)(object?)e.AzureEmail.Split(new char[] { '.', '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] == salesForm.SetterNrg
                ).OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
                salesForm.SetterAgentFullName = setterEmployee.AzureFullName;
                salesForm.SetterJobTitle = setterEmployee.AzureRole;
                salesForm.SetterEmail = setterEmployee.AzureEmail;
                salesForm.SetterTeam = setterEmployee.AzureTeam;
            }
    }
    
    context3.SalesForms.Add(salesForm);
    await context3.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

- If the "Setter" is a domestic employee (`Local Team`), the above query works fine and be able to save the setter info to the table
- If the "Setter" is a foreign employee (`CSR Team (Philippines)`), the above query won't work due to the `.Split` make the query too complex for `LINQ` expression. [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FkNy.png)

I tried multiple ways to resolve the issue, but none seemed ideal.

Comment: Can you implement Views in the database?

Comment: If you don't like the `Contains` solution, you can use `String.Substring` and `String.Index`, though you could have issues if the field isn't formatted properly (but so will your `Split` expression): `Convert.ToInt32(e.AzureEmail.Substring(e.AzureEmail.IndexOf('.')+1, e.AzureEmail.IndexOf('@')-e.AzureEmail.IndexOf('.')-1)) == salesForm.SetterNrg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your query to use `EndsWith`, which is translatable to the SQL:

```cs
public async Task Save_to_SalesForm()
{
    await using var context3 = await DBContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

    if (salesForm.SetterNrg != null)
    {
        Employee? setterEmployee = null;

        if (salesForm.CsTransferCategory == "Local Team")
        {   
            setterEmployee = await context3.Employees
                .Where(e => e.AzureAccountEnabled == 1 
                    && (int?)(object?)e.Nrg == salesForm.SetterNrg)
                .OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        else if (salesForm.CsTransferCategory == "CSR Team (Philippines)")
        {
            var toCheck = $".{salesForm.SetterNrg}@aaa-bbb.com";
            setterEmployee = await context3.Employees
                .Where(e => e.Nrg == null && e.AzureAccountEnabled == 1 
                    && e.AzureEmail.EndsWith(toCheck))
                .OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        if (setterEmployee != null)
        {
            salesForm.SetterAgentFullName = setterEmployee.AzureFullName;
            salesForm.SetterJobTitle = setterEmployee.AzureRole;
            salesForm.SetterEmail = setterEmployee.AzureEmail;
            salesForm.SetterTeam = setterEmployee.AzureTeam;
        }
    }

    context3.SalesForms.Add(salesForm);
    await context3.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in `e.AzureEmail.Contains("@aaa-bbb.com")`, there is no equivalent in sql to this. Try `EF.Functions.Like(e.AzureEmail, "%@aaa-bbb.com%")`. Everything from your expression will work if you materialize your data with `.ToList()` or something and perform it on the client, but it is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Changed to `EF.Functions.Like(e.AzureEmail, "%@aaa-bbb.com%") && (int?)(object?)e.AzureEmail.Split(new char[] { '.', '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] == salesForm.SetterNrg
                    ).ToList().OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();` Still showing error  `Translation of method 'string.Split' failed.`

Comment: `string.Split` also hasn't equivalent in sql. Have to change it to something translatable.

Comment: `Contains` translatable to the SQL. `Split` -  not.